# Async context not timing out

Tags: java, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I have been trying to use the timeout feature of the async context. But the behavior is highly intermittent. Sometimes the timeout happens, and many a times it doesn't. I am pasting my code here.

```
@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/test"},asyncSupported = true)
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> pq = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000);

private static ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,1,10, TimeUnit.SECONDS,pq);

public void service(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    TestListener listener = new TestListener();
    final AsyncContext asyncContext = servletRequest.startAsync();
    asyncContext.addListener(listener);
    asyncContext.setTimeout(100);
    Handler handler = new Handler(asyncContext);
    threadPoolExecutor.execute(handler);
}
}
```

The listener and the handler code is included below.

```
public class TestListener implements AsyncListener {
public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Event completed");
}

public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
    event.getAsyncContext().complete();
}

public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}



public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event){
    System.out.println("Timeout ");
    event.getAsyncContext().complete();
}
}

public class Handler implements Runnable {

private AsyncContext asyncContext;

public Handler(AsyncContext asyncContext){
    this.asyncContext = asyncContext;
}
public void run(){
    try {
        long currtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("slept for " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - currtime));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in thread ");
    }

    try{
        if(asyncContext != null){
            System.out.println("Completing async context " + " timeout is " + asyncContext.getTimeout());
            asyncContext.complete();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception in completing async context ");
    }
}
}
```

And the output is intermittent. Including the same here -

```
[ops@root combinedlogs]$ time curl "http://localhost:9001/mockresponse/test"

real    0m0.506s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s
[ops@root combinedlogs]$ time curl "http://localhost:9001/mockresponse/test"

real    0m0.159s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s
```

Catalina logs -

```
slept for 500
Completing async context  timeout is 100
Event completed

Timeout 
Event completed
slept for 500
Exception in completing async context
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Please help! Thanks for your time.

PS: The tomcat version is 7.0.37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the timeout and the sleep interval to more than 1 sec. 
For ex: Try a timeout interval of 2sec and a sleep for 5sec. 
It is possible that the servlet container does not detect timeouts less than 1 sec consistently. 
There were couple of bugs (marginally) related to such sub-second timeouts earlier in tomcat, like [this one](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53061). 
 I understand you are using a later version of tomcat than mentioned in that bug, still its worth the try.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! A higher timeout and a sleep value does a guarantee a timeout in every case. I had checked it earlier too! But it doesn't serve the purpose for me, when the timeout for me can be anything from 100 millis to 10000 millis. I had gone through the bug earlier too and thats why I decided to use the latest version of tomcat. Anyway, I don't think I can use the context timeout, I should rather be using a timer thread or a HashWheeledTimer. Thanks!